# TouchableHighlight: how do I preserve the underlayColor colore after press out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, touchablehighlight

I am using [TouchableHighlight](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight) for my component.   `<TouchableHighlight onLongPress={onLongPressButton} underlayColor="purple">` After I press out the component (I dont know if this is the right name of the action) the underlay color disappear. I want to preserve it and to make it stay. I tried using `background` color for the underlying `<div>` but it is not the same boundaries as `underlayColor`

*EDIT* - there is no initial collor of the component, so it is white (or whatever the default color is). No, I dont want the color to be changed on `onPress` event. Just to stay "highlighted" when I remove my finger away from the `onLongPress` event

Comment: What is your initial color used for the component? And onPress do you want it to remain purple?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onPressOut` prop function of `TouchableHighlight` and set state to change the color of the button.

It is called as soon as the touch is released even before onPress. The first function argument is an event in form of `PressEvent`.

Reference Link : https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpressout